# Flutter with tflite and teachable machine enquiries

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow-lite

Hi I am building an application to identify type of flower using Flutter and `Tflite` for machine learning. I have some problem after testing the app. The apps was able to identify types of flower which I trained on Google Teachable Machine, but I need it to show some kind of popup message or notification such as " This is not a flower" if other object was capture using camera.

Here is my code for your reference. How I can achieve this? I have take a look beside trained mode with label `Unknown_Object` on Google Teachable Machine, is there any other option I have?

```
     class _DetailsState extends State<Details> {
      final _screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
     
      void _takeScreenshot() async {
        final imageFile = await _screenshotController.capture();
        Share.shareFiles([imageFile.path], text: "share from this app");
      }
      bool loading = false;
      bool detecting = false;
      var output;
      List snapshotsFlower;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        loadModel();
      }
     
      //Load the Tflite model
      loadModel() async {
        setState(() {
          loading = true;
        });
     
        await Tflite.loadModel(
          model: "assets/model_unquant.tflite",
          labels: "assets/labels.txt",
        );
     
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
        classifyImage(widget.imageFile);
      }
     
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.file(
                        widget.imageFile,
                        //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.8,
     
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child:   Center(
                          child: Text(DemoLocalization.of(context).getTranslatedValue('result'),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 22.0,),
     
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (output != null) {
                            for (var v in snapshotsOfPlants) {
                              // print(v.data['name'].toString().toLowerCase());
                              // print(output[0]['label'].toString().split(' ')[1].toLowerCase());
                              if (v.data['name'].toString().toLowerCase() ==
                                  output[0]['label']
                                      .toString()
                                      .split(' ')[1]
                                      .toLowerCase()) {
                                /* Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  CupertinoPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Profile(
                                      post: v,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );*/
                                break;
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(output != null
                              ? output.isEmpty ? Icons.close : Icons.info
                              : FontAwesomeIcons.arrowAltCircleUp,
                            color: Colors.green,
     
                          size: 30.0,),
                          trailing: loading
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                              : detecting
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                              : Text(output != null
                              ? output.isEmpty
                              ? ''
                              : '${(output[0]['confidence'] * 100).floor()}' +
                              '%'
                              : '',
                            style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 1.0,
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                          ),
                          title: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              loading
                                  ? 'Wait'
                                  : detecting
                                  ? 'Scanning'
                                  : output != null
                                  ? output.isEmpty
                                  ? 'Unidentified image'
                                  //: 'Scanning show flower:  ${output[0]['label'].toString().split(' ')[1]}'
                                  : ' ${output[0]['label'].toString().split(' ')[1]}'
     
                                  : '',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 25.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
     
                      SizedBox(height: 60.0,),
     
     
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            textColor: Colors.black87,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            //onPressed: _takeScreenshot,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.share,
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(DemoLocalization.of(context).getTranslatedValue('share'),   style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                ),)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```